# How to get data based on 2 column condition in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, conditional-statements, cakephp-3.0, query-builder

I am trying to get some data in CakePHP 3.6. The condition is based on 2 column in a same table. first column is `status` as second column is `is_done_by_user`. So I want to fetch data if status is `1` or `2`. Also if the status is `3`. But for status 3 there need to be a check if the column `is_done_by_user` have value `1`.  So the final thing is. I want to get all the data with `status` `1` and `2`. And all the data with status `3` where `is_done_by_user` is `1`.
I have written the query but it is not working the way I am wanting. Here is the query that I had tried till now.

```
$query = $this->find('all',[
        'conditions' => [
            'Appointments.is_active' => 1,
            'Appointments.status IN' => (1,2,3),
            'Appointments.is_done_by_user' => 1
        ]
    ]);
```

Maybe I am far away from the actual query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query as written will find anything where all of the stated conditions are true, which is obviously not what you want. I think that this may be what you're looking for?

```
$query = $this->find('all',[
    'conditions' => [
        // This must always be true
        'Appointments.is_active' => 1,
        // One of the conditions in this list must be true
        'OR' => [
            // Either the status is 1 or 2
            'Appointments.status IN' => (1,2),
            // Or the status is 3 AND the user is 1
            [
                'Appointments.status' => 3,
                'Appointments.is_done_by_user' => 1,
            ],
        ],
    ]
]);
```